# Linux scheduled task not working in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, centos

The below cronjob is not working, although the task itself is working when I manually run it using `php artisan q:calc` .
I just added the path for php and artisan files as shown below, and pasted the command in the terminal.
Am I missing something ?

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/sharp/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: execute this code

/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/sharp/artisan schedule:run

Comment: Just like Armadou mentioned, why are you running php artisan q:calc at all?

Comment: that doesn't just get entered into the console, you have to actually add a cron entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That command is a cron entry, not something you run in terminal.

For example, under the specific user you would run (depending on your environment):

```
$ crontab -e
```

And paste the above to the crontab file.

You can learn more in the docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling

Or by [researching](https://google.com) how to add cron entries for your specific operating system.